# MOSS 2007 sharepoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way from a workflow to add a field to a list and prompt for its data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking SharePoint Designer Workflows, you can't.

You can have a secondary list named "Custom Fields" with "FieldName", "FieldValue", "ItemId" columns and relate them in the workflow using the Current Item Id or something.